# @Html.DropDownListFor como definir o valor padrão

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, razor, dropdownlist

Preciso definir o valor padrão apresentado por um `@Html.DropDownListFor`

Pesquisando achei: [@Html.DropDownListFor how to set default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23799091/html-dropdownlistfor-how-to-set-default-value)

Então, fiz no meu código:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.equipe, new SelectList(ViewBag.equiColaborador,"id","nome","Selecionar.."), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control"})
```

Mas, sem sucesso, sempre é apresentado o primeiro registro.

Meu `Controller`:

```
// GET: Colaboradores
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (Session["cod_cli"] != null)
        {
            string cod_cli = Session["cod_cli"].ToString();

            ViewBag.equiColaborador = db.Equipes.ToList();

            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer com DropDownList, que também é uma alternativa bacana:

Na Controller, se já quiser setar o valor padrão é assim:

```
ViewBag.equiColaborador = new SelectList(db.Equipes.ToList(), "seuValue", "seuText", "valorPadrao");
```

Sem valor padrão é assim:

```
ViewBag.equiColaborador = new SelectList(db.Equipes.ToList(), "seuValue", "seuText");
```

E na View assim:

```
@Html.DropDownList("equipe", (SelectList)ViewBag.equiColaborador, "-- Selecione --", new { @class = "form-control"})
```

Na View, onde está -- Selecione --, caso não tenha colocado valor padrão na Controller, você pode colocar ali o valor que virá selecionado.

Comment: Amigo, mas entre o `DropDownList` e o `DropDownListFor`, vejo o pessoal falando que o `DropDownListFor` é mais recomendado.. por ser fortemente tipado e etc.. oque vc acha?

Comment: Eu prefiro não utilizar DropDownList por ter uma tipação fraca, porém, em certos casos ela me serve mais comparado ao código mais tipado... Vai depender da sua necessidade, mas o resultado final para o usuário será o mesmo. Aqui tem uma boa explicação a respeito da comparação entre as duas, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182280/difference-between-dropdownlist-or-dropdownlistfor-html-helper

Comment: Amigo, perfeito., deu certo.. mas desse jeito, estou obrigando o usuario a selecionar um item.. teria como não ter essa obrigatoriedeade?

Comment: Onde está -- Selecione -- você pode trocar por -- Nenhum -- e na controller, ele receberá 0 ou null, dependendo do seu campo, ai é só fazer o tratamento lá, caso precise.